R Package no rustc reported prior to compilation
I have an R package that uses rust (ritkoken). I set up GH action runners (the standards from the usethis package), which test multiple OS and R versions.
The tests pass on all except Ubuntu-latest with R devel, where I get the warning (leading to a failed run): Warning:   No rustc version reported prior to compilation. However, I printed the rustc and cargo version before the step and it prints rustc 1.81.0 (eeb90cda1 2024-09-04) and cargo 1.81.0 (2dbb1af80 2024-08-20).
Where does the error come from and how can I fix this?
